# Accessing each value in array in a random order

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am making a guessing game where you are supposed to guess the capital of x country, the user is supposed to be prompted each time if they want to guess again there is an array of 15 CountryCards which I need to read through in a random order, I also cannot use the same card twice. When I run my current code I get through 14 iterations of the array and then the last one just gets stuck on the very start of the while loop (after inputting 1 into yesNo nothing happens) Here is the relevant code, any help is appreciated:

```java
while (CountryCard.instances < 30) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to guess the capital of a country?"
            + " Hit 1 for yes, or 2 for no (Case sensitive)");
    yesNo = input.nextInt();
    if (yesNo == 2) {
        return;
    }
    Random generator = new Random();
    int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(game.length);
    while (game[randomNumber].used == true && CountryCard.uses < 15) {
        randomNumber = generator.nextInt(game.length);
    }
    System.out.println("What is the Capital of "
            + game[randomNumber].getName() + "?");
    game[randomNumber].usedCard(1);
    guess = input.next();
    if (guess.equals(game[randomNumber].getCapital())) {
        System.out.println("Correct! :)");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect! :(");
    }
}//end of while
System.out.println("Thanks for playing :)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just shuffle your CountryCard list in place with [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) each time you play the game?

Something like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Game {
  private static final List<CountryCard> countryCards = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(
        new CountryCard("Canada", "Ottawa"),
        new CountryCard("USA", "Washington, D.C."),
        new CountryCard("France", "Paris"),
        new CountryCard("Germany", "Berlin"),
        new CountryCard("Spain", "Madrid"),
        new CountryCard("Turkey", "Ankara"),
        new CountryCard("Sudan", "Khartoum"),
        new CountryCard("Brazil", "Brasilia")
        // TODO add more countries as needed
     ));

  private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public void play() {
    // shuffle the country card list before playing
    Collections.shuffle(countryCards);
    for (CountryCard randomCountryCard: countryCards) {
        System.out.println("What is the capital of " + randomCountryCard.getName() + "?");

        String guess = input.next();

        if (randomCountryCard.getCapital().equalsIgnoreCase(guess)) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect!");
        }

        System.out.println("Answer: " + randomCountryCard.getCapital() + "\n");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.play();
  }
}

class CountryCard {
    private String name;
    private String capital;

    CountryCard(String name, String capital) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCapital() {
        return capital;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your collection/array has only 15 elements you can just use `Collections.shuffle()` and then iterate it.

If you don't want to change the initial array you can generate the collection with indexes (from zero to array.length) and then shuffle it.

Answer (score 1):

I previously mentioned in a comment that because you are randomly generating numbers in a while loop while looking for the last 1/15 number, it is very difficult to do. What you could do is implement open addressing collision handling. Of this, you can utilise either linear probing or double hashing.

Linear probing:
if random generated number is x, x is already used, instead of generating new random num, take x+1. If x+1 is used, take x+2 and so on.

double hashing:
if random generated number x is not used, continue as normal, but if it is used, utilise a hash to add a variable constant value to your x.
[image: Sample of double hashing]

Answer (score 0):

If it works only 14 times, then issue will be in the loop condition.
Try changing `CountryCard.uses<15` to `CountryCard.uses<=15`

Also check the value of game.length

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem unfortunately. Still has the same error

Comment: @Jonathan Bateman Can I see logic of these  codes.   game[randomNumber].usedCard(1); and while(game[randomNumber].used==true

Comment: Are you sure its getting stuck? In this case what i think is going on is that because you are generating random numbers in the while loop non-stop if the random number generated points to a used country. The thing is out of 15, 14 of them are already used! This is probably a case of poor implementation rather than code not working. If you keep generating random numbers, by probability, its very unlikely you will get the last unused country.